# How to set multi-reducers for Hadoop Program in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA in Ubuntu 14.04 to test my hadoop program. When I chang the number of reducer, I use the following code:

`job.setNumReduceTasks(3)`

I use `build artifacts` in IDEA to build a jar file and input `hadoop jar xxx.jar MyClass intput output` in linux shell. The output shows 3 files (`part-r-00000`, `part-r-00001`, `part-r-00002`), which is completely my expectation. However, when I runs the program in IDEA for convenience using the arguments `input/ output/`, the output result only contains one file `part-r-00000`. So I am wondering where goes wrong.

Comment: Does it actually go wrong? Like, does it run from IDEA? If so, I'd say no problem, right? Otherwise, could you elaborate what goes wrong exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run in local mode only one reducer will be used - there is no parallelism in local mode. Nothing is going wrong with your code here.

Also see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation:

> Standalone Operation
>
> By default, Hadoop is configured to run in a non-distributed mode, as a single Java process. This is useful for debugging.